# How can I mock an autowired instance in an abstract test class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have an abstract service class which autowires a specified type of repository.

```java
abstract class SomeService<T extends SomeRepository<U>, U ...> {

    @Autowrired
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @Getter(PROTECTED)
    private U repositoryInstance;
}
```

Now I'm trying to create an abstract test class for subclasses of the service class.

```java
@SpringBootTest
abstract class SomeServiceTest<T extends SomeService<U>, U extends SomeRepository<V>, V ...> {

    @Autowrired
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @Getter(PROTECTED)
    private T serviceInstance;

    // DOES NOT WORK!
    @MockBean
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @Getter(PROTECTED)
    private U repositoryInstance; // != serviceInstance.repositoryInstance();
}
```

But mocking the bean in a test class of actual service class works.

```java
class OtherServiceTest
        extends SomeServiceTest<OtherService, OtherRepository, ...> {

    @TestConfiguration
    OtherServiceTestConfiguration {

        // WORKS!!!
        // == serviceInstance().repositoryInstance();
        @MockBean private OtherRepository repositoryInstance;
    }
}

class AnotherServiceTest
        extends SomeServiceTest<AnotherService, AnotherRepository, ...> {

    // WORKS!!!
    // == serviceInstance().repositoryInstance();
    @MockBean private AnotherRepository repositoryInstance;
}
```

How can I mock the `SomeServiceTest#repositoryInstance` so that it refers the same object as `SomeServiceTest#serviceInstance.repositoryInstance()`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is @Autowire, because I use @Autowired. But, as far I know, use autowire in the object declaration is a bad practice.

Instead of:

```
@Autowired
MyObject myObject;
```

Use it in the constructor:

```
Repository repository;    

@Autowired
public SomeService(Repository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

And, in your test:

```
class SomeServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Repository repositoryMock;

    private Service serviceUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void init() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         serviceUnderTest = new Service(repositoryMock);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare a default and an all-args constructor. The DI framework will instantiate via the first one, injecting the autowired fields, whereas you can instantiate with the all-args one from your test class, passing mock objects as constructor arguments.